# key.Exists return true for expired key

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

May be I missed something general, and I am sorry for that.
But in my tests, when I check expired key (hash) for exists, it returns true:

here "cache" is IDatabase instance

```
// This will return true
var exists = cache.KeyExists(key);
// This will return null
var ttl = cache.KeyTimeToLive(key);
// This will return null
var fullWait = cache.HashGetAsync(key, "full", flags: CommandFlags.None);
```

Also, set with When.NotExists will work:

```
cache.HashSetAsync(key, "full", value, When.NotExists, CommandFlags.PreferMaster);
```

**Update:**

@Marc_Gravell answer helped me to find the issue in my tests:
I am receiving this strange behavior when I am setting up the expiration to be too short (~500 milliseconds).
When I did change it to be 1 or 2 seconds - my tests are passing now.

In **changed** Marc's example, this also happens ( I changed expiration to 400 ms):

```
[Test]
    public void Exec()
    {
        var key = "testKey";
        using (var conn = CreateConnection())
        {
            var cache = conn.GetDatabase();

            // setup some data
            cache.KeyDelete(key);
```

//                cache.HashSet(key, "full", "some value");
//                cache.KeyExpire(key, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

```
            cache.HashSetAsync(key, "full", "some value", When.NotExists, CommandFlags.PreferMaster);
            cache.HashSetAsync(key, "last_accessesed", "some other data", When.NotExists, CommandFlags.PreferMaster);
            cache.KeyExpireAsync(key, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(400), CommandFlags.FireAndForget);



            // test while exists
            var exists = cache.KeyExists(key);
            var ttl = cache.KeyTimeToLive(key);
            var fullWait = cache.HashGetAsync(key, "full", flags: CommandFlags.None);
            Assert.IsTrue(exists, "key exists");
            Assert.IsNotNull(ttl, "ttl");
            Assert.AreEqual("some value", (string)fullWait.Result);
```

brings

```
  ttl
  Expected: not null
  But was:  null
```

**Update 2:**

This code worked fine for me yesterday, but does not work now.

```
   private ConnectionMultiplexer CreateConnection()
    {
        ConnectionMultiplexer connection =ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
     "myserver.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=false,password=password-here");

        return connection;
    }

        [Ignore]
        [Test]
        public void Exec()
        {
        var key = "testKey";
        using (var conn = CreateConnection())
        {
            var cache = conn.GetDatabase();

            // setup some data
            cache.KeyDelete(key);
            cache.HashSetAsync(key, "full", "some value", When.NotExists, CommandFlags.PreferMaster);
            cache.HashSetAsync(key, "last_accessesed", "some other data", When.NotExists, CommandFlags.PreferMaster);
            cache.KeyExpireAsync(key, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(2000), CommandFlags.FireAndForget);

            // test while exists
            var exists = cache.KeyExists(key);
            var ttl = cache.KeyTimeToLive(key);
            var fullWait = cache.HashGetAsync(key, "full", flags: CommandFlags.None);
            Assert.IsTrue(exists, "not expired key exists");
            Assert.IsNotNull(ttl, "ttl");
            Assert.AreEqual("some value", (string)fullWait.Result);

            // wait for expiry
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));

            // test once expired
            exists = cache.KeyExists(key);
            ttl = cache.KeyTimeToLive(key);
            fullWait = cache.HashGetAsync(key, "full", flags: CommandFlags.None);
            Assert.IsFalse(exists, "expired key exists");
            Assert.IsNull(ttl, "ttl");
            Assert.IsNull((string)fullWait.Result);
        }
    }
```

Line

```
Assert.IsFalse(exists, "expired key exists");
```

returns

```
  expired key exists
  Expected: False
  But was:  True
```

Changing to use seconds did not help:

```
  cache.KeyExpireAsync(key, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(3), CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
  ...
  // wait for expiry
  Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

returns same result ( Assert.IsFalse(exists, "expired key exists"))

```
  expired key exists
  Expected: False
  But was:  True
```

Comment: I will re-run with your example tomorrow, but: what server version are you using? (This matters because second versus millisecond timeout precision is a feature of the server version)

Comment: I am running against current MS Azure Redis. Also, from my tests I see that 700-800 ms is also good enough. May be this is some kind of latency accessing Azure from on-premise.

Comment: hmm, it seems not working once more. Starting to think it somehow related to MS Azure. Updating the question.

Comment: If you have high latency, then yes it is entirely possible for the first "exists" check to return true, and the subsequent "ttl" check to return null - there is an inherent race condition in making these separate requests. Is is possible that this is what you are seeing?

Comment: But in this case, if after ttl = null I'll perform exists - it should return false. Isn't it? I'll try later.

Comment: that depends: did you actually set a timeout? ttl will also return null if there was no timeout set. To minimize race conditions, it should be preferred to use the `*Async` API to issue all the requests at (roughly) the same moment, then collect the results afterwards. Doing this inside a transaction or as a script would be even better, by avoiding the race issues.

Comment: Is it possible that KeySetAsync will take more than 1 sec? In the code from your test, cache.HashSetAsync(key, "full", "some value", When.NotExists, CommandFlags.PreferMaster);
cache.KeyExpireAsync(key, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(1), CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
var exists = cache.KeyExists(key);
This exists return false for 1 second, true for 2 seconds

Comment: impossible to answer without a reproducible scenario; note that due to rounding, it isn't necessarily an entire second when it reports things - it depends a bit on whet server version it has been able to detect, though (`ttl` vs `pttl`, `expire` vs `pexpire`, etc)

Comment: For a while, Azure's redis implementation had only 1 second precision, not millisecond level precision on timeouts, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this; you say that `KeyExists` returns `true` and `KeyTimeToLive` returns `null` - that sounds like a key that doesn't have an expiry, then - but which exists.

You then say that `fullWait` returns `null` - that can happen if the hash at `key` doesn't have a field set against the name `"full"`.

It is expected that `HashSetAsync` will *work*; the interesting question is: does it return `true` or `false` when awaited?

This passes, for example:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SO24807536 : TestBase
{
    public void Exec()
    {
        var key = Me();
        using(var conn = Create())
        {
            var cache = conn.GetDatabase();

            // setup some data
            cache.KeyDelete(key);
            cache.HashSet(key, "full", "some value");
            cache.KeyExpire(key, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            // test while exists
            var exists = cache.KeyExists(key);
            var ttl = cache.KeyTimeToLive(key);
            var fullWait = cache.HashGetAsync(key, "full",
                flags: CommandFlags.None);
            Assert.IsTrue(exists, "key exists");
            Assert.IsNotNull(ttl, "ttl");
            Assert.AreEqual("some value", (string)fullWait.Result);

            // wait for expiry
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));

            // test once expired
            exists = cache.KeyExists(key);
            ttl = cache.KeyTimeToLive(key);
            fullWait = cache.HashGetAsync(key, "full",
                flags: CommandFlags.None);                
            Assert.IsFalse(exists, "key exists");
            Assert.IsNull(ttl, "ttl");
            Assert.IsNull((string)fullWait.Result);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm happy to investigate, but so far it looks like it is performing correctly.